# Trigger screen mirror from inside the app

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

Is there a way to trigger the "Screen Mirror" functionality from inside the app?
I am doing conference via RTC and it would be super nice to be able to just airplay it the appleTV. Displaying the airplay control and selecting a target does nothing (no output).